# Javascript Logic missing

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, conditional-statements

I am new to this coding world and learning Javascript as a first language. I'm in the middle of solidifying my javascript skills that i've gathered so far. The question i have is what am i missing in my code.. maybe a pointer not the complete answer will help

The aim of my code is simply to get inputs from the end users and if the user inputs matches what value i have stored in my number_to_guess variable than the output should be "well done smart ass" otherwise please try again with a limit of 3/4 attempts

The "please try again" is where i'm having trouble the looping only happens once.

```
let number_of_guesses = 0
let number_to_guess = 50
let limit = 4
let guess = prompt("enter a guess")

while (guess != number_to_guess) {
    if (guess != number_to_guess) {
        guess = prompt("enter another guess")
        number_of_guesses = number_of_guesses + 1
    } else {
        console.log("you smart ass")
    }
}

if (number_of_guesses === limit) {
    console.log("you have run out goes")
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close, just had a problem with your while loop:

```
let number_of_guesses = 0;
let number_to_guess = 50;
let limit = 4;
let guess = prompt("Guess A Number");

while (guess != number_to_guess && number_of_guesses < limit) {

    var remaining = limit - number_of_guesses;

    if (remaining == 1)
        guess = prompt(`Guess Again (Last Chance)`);
    else
        guess = prompt(`Guess Again (${remaining} Tries Remaining)`);

    number_of_guesses = number_of_guesses + 1;

    if (guess == number_to_guess)
        alert("Correct!");
    else if (number_of_guesses == limit)
        alert("Too Many Tries...");
}
```

Comment: Cheers John, i made some fixes to the current code and it works using your "remaining variable" as well as the extra loop condition Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your while loop condition. You have `while (guess!=number_to_guess);`. Because of the semicolon, this effectively shortcuts your while loop with an empty body. This is why your loop isn't running correctly. Try with the following:

```
let number_of_guesses = 0; 
let number_to_guess = 50;  
let limit = 4; 
let guess = prompt("enter a guess");

while (guess !== parseInt(number_to_guess) && number_of_guesses < limit) {
  guess = prompt("enter another guess");
  number_of_guesses++;
}

if(number_of_guesses===limit) {   
  console.log("you have run out goes");
}
else {
  console.log("you smart ass");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a better way to do it without a while loop. This uses recursion and is more performant way to solve this.

```
let number_of_guesses = 0 
let number_to_guess = 50  
let limit = 4 

const guess = () => {
    let userGuess = prompt("enter a guess")
    if(parseInt(userGuess) !== number_to_guess){
        number_of_guesses++
        if(number_of_guesses < limit){
            guess()
        } else {
            console.log("you have run out goes")
        }
    } else {
        console.log("you smart ass") 
    }
}
guess()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let number_of_guesses = 0
let number_to_guess = 50
let limit = 3
let guess = prompt("enter a guess")

while (guess != number_to_guess && number_of_guesses<limit) {
   var remaining = limit - number_of_guesses;
    if (guess != number_to_guess) {
        guess = prompt("enter another guess" + remaining)
        number_of_guesses = number_of_guesses + 1
    } 
}

if (number_of_guesses === limit) {
    console.log("you have run out goes")
} else if (guess=number_to_guess) {
  console.log("well done you smarty")
}
```